# Inability to view my flask application on the web

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

I have been working on a flask application and it has been working just fine. however, for a couple of hours now, i have not been able to run my application on the web. After running the script on command line as usual, i would copy the ip address to my browser in order to display its content but will not respond anymore. I have tried changing port, and other troubleshooting i suppose should work but has still not been able to get it fixed. Any assistance is highly appreciated.
The error message is " this site can not be reached" when is actually running on the server in command line.

Comment: Could you please copy+paste your flask command and the entire output from the command line?

Comment: (flaskenv) C:\Users\ADMIN\flaskenv>set FLASK_DEBUG=1

(flaskenv) C:\Users\ADMIN\flaskenv>flask run
 * Serving Flask app "Flaask_blog.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 254-534-538
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: @Debby Jimmy You can not see your application on the internet or in your browser? Have you tried to enter the address **127.0.0.1:5000** in your browser?

Comment: Yes. I have done that severally. It was working fine in the early hours of yesterday. It just stopped about the time i posted it here. I have tried changing port, checking my firewall protections, all to no avail. Thank u for your concern.